# What does "the author’s title" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The sentences below are from [In France, They Call It ‘Happiness Therapy’](http://rendezvous.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/03/07/in-france-they-call-it-happiness-therapy/)

> In an online poll the Web site Newsring recently asked its readers if
>   they were pro or con film title translation; 78 percent responded
>   against.
>
> In 2003, Mr. Ernst was in charge is distributing Stephen Frears’s
>   “Dirty Pretty Things.” “It was a difficult decision,” he said. “It was
>   **the author’s title**, and a beautiful one, so we didn’t want to change
>   it. It was also quite easy to understand.”
>
> In the end, they went with the same title, but with “Loin de chez eux” (Far From Home) as a subtitle.
>
> And sometimes, keeping the English titles, as complicated as it may
>   be, works out fine. The perfect example: “Eternal Sunshine of a
>   Spotless Mind,” which kept its mysterious title and did very well at
>   the French box office.

I know “Dirty Pretty Things” is a English movie's title and  Mr. Ernst was unwilling to translate it to French.But what does" the author’s title" mean here ? Does it mean" the original title" or "a famous title" or something else?

Comment: That IHT/NYT article has an error in their  “perfect example”: The name actually is *Eternal Sunshine of **the** Spotless Mind* ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Sunshine_of_the_Spotless_Mind), [2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338013/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The original title* is the first title given to a work.  It's possible, though not common, for someone besides the author to give a work its first title.

*The author's title* is the title the author came up with.  It may or may not be *the original title*, but most of the time it is.

Answer (score 1):

It means the title given from Stephen Frears, the director of the movie. You can also say *the original title*, since they are talking about translating the title.